# Android - Menu Item cannot be resolved to a type in onOptionsItemSelected()

Tags: android, menu

I created a simple activity (with a menu) and tried adding menu items but they don't show up when trying to actually give them some function in the onOptionsItemSelected() method. I'm not sure why it's not working, as I did the exact same thing in the menu for the main activity and it worked just fine. When typing in android.R.id.add_screen_submit_button for example, it is not recognized as existing. And if I forcefully just type it in and leave it the message "add_screen_submit_button cannot be resolved or is not a field" comes up. The menu is also in the correct folder (I actually just left it as is when creating the Activity). Thanks in advance.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/add_screen_submit_button"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/add_screen_ok"
    android:icon="@drawable/accept_icon" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/add_screen_cancel_button"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/add_screen_cancel"
    android:icon="@drawable/cancel_icon" />

</menu>
```

Here's the code

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //setupActionBar();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    case android.R.id.add_screen_submit_button:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;  
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
android.R.id.home:
```

to

```
R.id.home:
```

and the same with the other one.

`android.R` is for sdk resources and `R.id.some_id` is for `id`s you create

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much for the quick response. The home one didn't need the "android" removed since the up default button is created automatically. But removing it from the items I created worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry I wasn't paying attention to what that one was. Glad I could help